# How can i use validate my signup form in php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to check all my signup fiels to be validate in php but it seems it not take other validation except email validation. Please have a look so that can help me to bug my errors.
Thank you.

Here its my signup process...

```
if($_POST['action']=="signup")
     {
    $name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['email']);
    $bankid = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['bankid']);
    $phone  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['phone']);
    $password  = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);
    $query = "SELECT email FROM users where email='".$email."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    $numResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // Validate email address
        {
     $message =  "E - post Redan also!!";
        }
    elseif($numResults>=1)
        {
     $message = $email." E-post redan finns!!";
        }
        else
        {
                                                mysqli_query($connection,"insert into users(name,email,bankid,phone,password) values('".$name."','".$email."','".$bankid."','".$phone."','".md5($password)."')");
         $message = "Registrera framg&aring;ngsrikt!!";
        }
      }
```

Comment: Not sure why you've done it this route `if($_POST['action']=="signup")` I'd of done: `if(isset($_POST['signup']))` Are you getting any MySQLI errors?

Comment: @Option yes its not validating even email... thats makes the error also.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to validate all the fields of your sign up form on submit, correct?

There are [various examples](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sanitize-and-validate-data-with-php-filters--net-2595) online of using `filter_var` in PHP - a bit of Googling will get you the answers.

I would recommend using a validation library that's built to help you make sure your code is secure. An example of such library is: https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP

If you have a look at the source code for GUMP, there are more examples using filter_var:

https://github.com/Wixel/GUMP/blob/master/gump.class.php#L878

```
filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)
filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
// etc
```